# Holding a future value of a promise in a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise

I have a database that's calling for a list of recent messages. Each message is an object and is stored as an Array of these message objects in chatListNew.

Each message object has a property "from", which is the ID of the user who posted it. What I want to do, is loop through this Array and append the actual profile information of the "From" user into the object itself. That way when the Frontend receives the information, it has access to one specific message's sender's profile in that respective message's fromProfile property.

I thought about looping through each one and doing a Promise.All for every one, however, that's hugely expensive if only a handful over users posted hundreds of messages. It would make more sense to **only run the mongoose query once for each user**. So I invented a caching system.

However, I'm confused as to how to store the promise of a future value inside of an array element. I thought setting the "fromProfile" to the previously called promise would magically hold this promise until the value was resolved. So I used Promise.all to make sure all the promises were completed and then returned by results, but the promises I had stored in the arrays were not the values I had hoped for.

Here is my code:

```
//chatListNew = an array of objects, each object is a message that has a "from" property indicating the person-who-sent-the-message's user ID

let cacheProfilesPromises = []; // this will my basic array of the promises called in the upcoming foreach loop, made for Promise.all
let cacheProfilesKey = {}; // this will be a Key => Value pair, where the key is the message's "From" Id, and the value is the promise retrieving that profile
let cacheProfileIDs = []; // this another Key => Value pair, which basically stores to see if a certain "From" Id has already been called, so that we can not call another expensive mongoose query


chatListNew.forEach((message, index) => {
    if(!cacheProfileIDs[message.from]) { // test to see if this user has already been iterated, if not
        let thisSearch = User.findOne({_id : message.from}).select('name nickname phone avatar').exec().then(results => {return results}).catch(err => { console.log(err); return '???' ; }); // Profile retrieving promise
        cacheProfilesKey[message.from] = thisSearch;
        cacheProfilesPromises.push(thisSearch); // creating the Array of promises
        cacheProfileIDs[message.from] = true;
    }

    chatListNew[index]["fromProfile"] = cacheProfilesKey[message.from]; // Attaching this promise (hoping it will become a value once promise is resolved) to the new property "fromProfile"
});

Promise.all(cacheProfilesPromises).then(_=>{ // Are all promises done?
    console.log('Chat List New: ', chatListNew);
    res.send(chatListNew);
});
```

And this is my console output:

```
Chat List New:  [ { _id: '5b76337ceccfa2bdb7ff35b5',
updatedAt: '2018-08-18T19:50:53.105Z',
createdAt: '2018-08-18T19:50:53.105Z',
from: '5b74c1691d21ce5d9a7ba755',
conversation: '5b761cf1eccfa2bdb7ff2b8a',
type: 'msg',
content: 'Hey everyone!',
fromProfile:
 Promise { emitter: [EventEmitter], emitted: [Object], ended: true } },
{ _id: '5b78712deccfa2bdb7009d1d',
updatedAt: '2018-08-18T19:41:29.763Z',
createdAt: '2018-08-18T19:41:29.763Z',
from: '5b74c1691d21ce5d9a7ba755',
conversation: '5b761cf1eccfa2bdb7ff2b8a',
type: 'msg',
content: 'Yo!',
fromProfile:
 Promise { emitter: [EventEmitter], emitted: [Object], ended: true } } ]
```

Whereas I was hoping for something like:

```
Chat List New:  [ { _id: '5b76337ceccfa2bdb7ff35b5',
updatedAt: '2018-08-18T19:50:53.105Z',
createdAt: '2018-08-18T19:50:53.105Z',
from: '5b74c1691d21ce5d9a7ba755',
conversation: '5b761cf1eccfa2bdb7ff2b8a',
type: 'msg',
content: 'Hey everyone!',
fromProfile:
 Promise {name: xxx, nickname: abc... etc} },
{ _id: '5b78712deccfa2bdb7009d1d',
updatedAt: '2018-08-18T19:41:29.763Z',
createdAt: '2018-08-18T19:41:29.763Z',
from: '5b74c1691d21ce5d9a7ba755',
conversation: '5b761cf1eccfa2bdb7ff2b8a',
type: 'msg',
content: 'Yo!',
fromProfile:
 {name: xxx, nickname: abc... etc} } ]
```

Thank you guys! Open to other ways of accomplishing this :)
Pete

Comment: That's not how Promise.all works!

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn’t merge the from fromProfile into each item in the list. I’d keep them separate and put that work onto the client. Your payload will be much smaller, and the client could even cache the fromProfiles if needed. You could still make it be one request, by implementing what’s called “sideloading”. Essentially your json would have two root nodes, “fromProfiles” which is an array, and “chatItems” which is that array you have right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a `Promise` is assigned to a variable, that variable will *always* be a `Promise`, unless the variable is reassigned. You need to get the *results* of your `Promises` from your `Promise.all` call.

There's also no point to a `.then` that simply returns its argument, as with your `.then(results => {return results})` - you can leave that off entirely, it doesn't do anything.

Construct the array of Promises, and also construct an array of `from` properties, such that each Promise's `from` corresponds to the item in the other array at the same index. That way, once the `Promise.all` completes, you can transform the array of resolved values into an object indexed by `from`, after which you can iterate over the `chatListNew` and assign the *resolved* value to the `fromProfile` property of each message:

```
const cacheProfilesPromises = [];
const messagesFrom = [];

chatListNew.forEach((message, index) => {
  const { from } = message;
  if(messagesFrom.includes(from)) return;
  messagesFrom.push(from);
  const thisSearch = User.findOne({_id : from})
    .select('name nickname phone avatar')
    .exec()
    .catch(err => { console.log(err); return '???' ; });
  cacheProfilesPromises.push(thisSearch);
});

Promise.all(cacheProfilesPromises)
  .then((newInfoArr) => {
    // Transform the array of Promises into an object indexed by `from`:
    const newInfoByFrom = newInfoArr.reduce((a, newInfo, i) => {
      a[messagesFrom[i]] = newInfo;
      return a;
    }, {});

    // Iterate over `chatListNew` and assign the *resolved* values:
    chatListNew.forEach((message) => {
      message.fromProfile = newInfoByFrom[message.from];
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me :)

Answer (score 1):

A Promise is an object container, like a Array. The difference being that a Promise holds a value that will sometimes be.

So, since you do not know when the value will be `resolved` in Promise jargon, generally you tell the promise what to do with the value, when it is resolved.

So for example,

```
function (id) {
   const cache = {}
   const promise = expensiveQuery(id)
   // promise will always be a promise no matter what
   promise.then(value => cache[id] = value)
   // After the callback inside then is executed,
   // cache has the value you are looking for,
   // But the following line will not give you the value
  return cache[params.id]
}
```

Now, what you might do to fix that code is, return the promise  when the query is run for the first time, or return the cached value.

```
// I moved this out of the function scope to make it a closure
// so the cache is the same across function calls
const cache = {}
function (id) {
   if(cache[id]) return cache[id]
   const promise = expensiveQuery(id)
   // promise will always be a promise no matter what
   promise.then(value => cache[id] = value)
   // now we just return the promise, because the query
   // has already run
  return promise
}
```

Now you'll have a value or a promise depending on whether the function has already been called once before for that id, and the previous call has been resolved.

But that's a problem, because you want to have a consistent API, so lets tweak it a little.

```
// I moved this out of the function scope to make it a closure
// so the cache is the same across function calls
const cache = {}
function cachingQuery (id) {
   if(cache[id]) return cache[id]
   const promise = expensiveQuery(id)
   // Now cache will hold promises and guarantees that
   // the expensive query is called once per id
   cache[id] = promise
   return promise
}
```

Ok, now you always have a promise, and you only call the query once. Remember that doing `promise.then` doesn't perform another query, it simply uses the last result.

And now that we have a caching query function, we can solve the other problem. That is adding the result to the message list.

And also, we dont' want to have a cache that survives for too long, so the cache can't be right on the top scope. Let's wrap all this inside a cacheMaker function, it will take an expensive operation to run, and it will return a function that will cache the results of that function, based on its only argument.

```
function makeCacher(query) {
  const cache = {}
  return function (id) {
     if(cache[id]) return cache[id]
     const promise = query(id)
     cache[id] = promise
     return promise
  }
}
```

Now we can try to solve the other problem, which is, assign the user to each message.

```
const queryUser = makeCacher((id) => User.findOne({_id : id})
    .select('name nickname phone avatar')
    .exec())

const fromUsers = chatListNew.map((message) => queryUser(message.from))

Promise.all(fromUsers)
  .then(users =>
    chatListNew.map(message =>
         Object.assign(
           {},
           message,
           { fromProfile: users.find(x => x._id === message.from)})))
  .then(messagesWitUser => res.json(messagesWitUser) )
  .catch(next) // send to error handler in express
```

Comment: I appreciate you. Thanks for helping me out!